# PHP SphinxClient can't get long time execution queries results

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm trying to get the result for some long-time executed queries. Each query has the same structure:

```
    @CODE (ZZZZZZ|YYYYY...) @FIELD2 YES
```

Each query successful finishes (I'm using `searchd --console` to check it) in 70-100 seconds.
But PHP code stopping to wait for the response in 60-th second and drops an error

```
  received zero-sized searchd response
```

Looks like connection dropped or so?
I'm using regular SphinxClient. The PHP code for calling sphinx search looking like that:

```
$this->client->SetServer($this->host, $this->port);
$this->client->SetArrayResult(true);
$this->client->SetWeights(array(100, 1));
$this->client->SetMatchMode($this->mode);
$this->client->SetMaxQueryTime(5000000);
$this->client->SetLimits($this->offset, $this->limit, ($this->limit > 1000) ? $this->limit : 1000);
$this->result = $this->client->Query($this->query, $this->index);
```

PHP configured with

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
```

Is this possible to set some system settings - so script will be able to wait for the response longer time? I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.3 Lenny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting setConnectionTimeout?

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setconnecttimeout

---

Although might be better to set stream_set_timeout
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php
would have to hotwire sphinxapi.php to add a call to it.